# Unable to pass header through the VHS handler in safari

Tags: safari, streaming, http-live-streaming, audio-streaming, video.js

I'm trying to add a token header to my player. It worked for Chrome but failed for safari as I'm not able to get the VHS handler for safari which I'm able to access in chrome. Below is the code I'm using which is working in chrome.

```
if (player.tech(true) && player.tech(true).hls) {
  player.tech(true).hls.xhr.beforeRequest = options => {
    var headers = options.headers || {};
    headers['Authorization'] = `JWT ${testToken.access_token}`;
    options.headers = headers;
    return options
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can add/attach a header to the player? I'm already using the `"@videojs/http-streaming"` package in my project.

Answer (score 2):

Safari will use native playback rather than VHS on desktop and iPad by default. You can force the use of VHS with a player setup option:

```js
videojs('my_player', {html5: {vhs: { overrideNative: true }}});
```

It's not possible to use VHS for playback on iPhone, since there is not Media Source Extensions support.

Comment: After doing this am successfully getting VHS handler but my player stopped working i.e it stopped stream and now am getting VIDEOJS ERROR CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE